# accessing multiple variables with i

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

If I have variable1, variable2 and variable 3. Is there anyway to get that variable with i?

Such as getting variablei , where i = 1.

Following code I think illustrates what I am talking about.

```
    ArrayList networkSetupData = new ArrayList(count);
    for(int i =0 ; i != count ; count--)
    {
        networkSetupData.add(dropDown[i]);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's amazing how you solved your own problem in that code sample.

Comment: in this for loop you continuously add the same value while count != 0. Why do you need such a lot of code. There is a method Collections.nCopies(int n, Object o) which return List of n objects

Comment: @Martin: no, he simply adds value at 0 position of dropDown

Comment: > new ArrayList(count);
This set a capacity of List, but not its size. Be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should basically restructure your code to have a single array or collection variable instead. You've got three variables which are clearly related, and which you want to access by index: you want a collection.

Instead of declaring `dropDown1`, `dropDown2`, `dropDown3`, you should declare `dropDowns` either as a `List<DropDown>` or possibly a `DropDown[]`. Then you can access them by index at any time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I can rewrite that section to use an array. Thanks.